# Add url segment using IIS URL rewriting

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Is is possible to use url re-writing to add a segment in the url e.g.: adding a version number

For example, the raw input url should be something like: `http://host.com/**v2**/categories/5` and I want it rewritten to `http://host.com/categories/5`

We have an additional rewrite rule to add the .svc segment to the url, so the web.config rewrite section looks something like this:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Remove version segment from the Url" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="^v2(.*)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Add ServiceHost.svc to the Url" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="ServiceHost.svc/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```